# Azure SQL Server Login failed after Free-trial

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-server

I am currently using Azure for studies. My 30-day free trial is now over. However, I can see that after this free trial, there would be a period of another 11 months or so of free products, list in which SQL Server is included.

I have a SQL Server database hosted under this account and I can no longer access it. Would not it be included in this one year trial? Or should I start paying now? I want to use it for studies and I cannot pay much.

Password is correct, because I noted it down and I have it in my `web.config`. But I am still getting this error:

> Login failed for user XXX. ... Error: 18456

Comment: You could create a new account and create a new Azure SQL database with Basic price tier and only need 4.9$/month.

Comment: Can you show us more details for the error message?

Comment: Also, if you set it to auto shutdown its another really cheap option.

Comment: I suggest that you log into azure.portal.com and confirm that your subscription is still active

Comment: Hi RNA, I found the answer. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According on the [Azure free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/#new-products) document:

**What happens once I use my $200 free credit or I’m at the end of 30 days?**

We’ll notify you so you can decide if you want to upgrade to pay-as-you-go pricing and remove the spending limit. If you do, you’ll have access to free products.* If you don’t, your account and products will be disabled, and you'll need to upgrade to resume usage.

It gives you the answer. That's why you can't access your Azure SQL database.

You could upgrade to pay-as-you-go pricing and continue to use the Azure SQL database in the left 11 months for free.

Azure SQL database has many price tiers,  if your database is not very large, you can change to the Basic price tier and only need 4.99$/month after one yeas later:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, it was very helpful, I did not know about that. Cheers mate. Have a great weekend.